# Unable to add ngModel directive to angular material autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to add an autocomplete field to a page in my angular app.

I added below in my template.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Pick one" [(ngModel)]="entity.type" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

But, I get following error when I navigate to the page.

> ERROR Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control
>   with unspecified name attribute

Error goes away if I remove `[(ngModel)]="entity.type"` directive from the template.

What is the reason for this error? Is there any way I can fix it?

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jaj4da) for the issue. Error is shown in the console, which can be opened from the right bottom of the page.

Comment: share your ts code

Comment: and more html if it is okay with you

Comment: @NoHoney_k1ll added a stackblitz example

Comment: That's because you're using `ngModel` _and_ the `name` attribute, which conflicts each other. Either remove the `name` attribute, the `ngModel` attribute, or use [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: @Edric I have removed `name` attribute in the stackblitz, but still the issue is there. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was caused by the [TrimValueAccessorModule](https://github.com/khashayar/ng-trim-value-accessor) which I had used in the app. When I remove the module, issue gets fixed.

I could exclude the autocomplete from the TrimValueAccessorModule by using following class name in the `input` tag, so that I can fix the issue without removing `TrimValueAccessorModule` entirely.

```
class="ng-trim-ignore"
```